# How to link all the contacts to a customer

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I have a customer and contacts. But now I want to link all the contacts to the customer.

But I get for name a empty value back.

This is the code:

```
BussinesContactName.SETFILTER(BussinesContactName."No.", "<Contact>"."No." );
    FOR i := 0 TO BussinesContactName.COUNT DO BEGIN
      IF  BussinesContactName.FINDSET  THEN BEGIN REPEAT  
        MESSAGE(BussinesContactName."Contact Name" );
      UNTIL  BussinesContactName.NEXT <= 0;
      END;
     END;
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can link only one Contact to a Customer. If your Customer is a company and you want to link Contact to that Company you need to create Contacts to the Contact which is linked to the Customer.

I hope it helps